# Factor analysis (or similar) for data set with both continuous and dichotomous variables (+control for age?)

Tags: binary-data, factor-analysis, continuous-data, item-response-theory, polychoric

As you can tell from the title I'm in a bit of a fix. I have a data set with three continuous variables and one dichotomous one. Data collected from four groups. The data set is a developmental measure, so each of the participants have a score for each variable, and the participants vary in age.

My goal is to test the factor structure for these four measures (in each of the groups). The hypothesis is that in **one** of the four groups performance on the four measures is related to a single underlying factor, while in the other three groups this is not the case.

What is the best way to test this? I've been digging around item response theory, factor analysis and polychoric matrices, but haven't found anything that could extract factors for a mixed continuous/dichotomous data set.

Also, does the fact that the participants are not matched for age across groups matter here? I'm thinking not, but then it's possible in theory that the factor structure changes across development...